# Wordpress website intermittently tries to redirect to a scam website lan05(dot)biz

Tags: wordpress, redirect, malware

I know very little about website design, etc, and a few year ago inherited the responsibility of keeping my org's website  current: I add pictures to a slideshow, change the text on the main page to reflect current events, that sort of thing.  In the last week or so I've noticed that occasionally I can't get to the website's public-facing end: it will try to redirect to the scam website above, but the browsers don't allow this so  I just get an error message. When I used a website security site, it said there was a missing intermediate security certificate.

The website operates via wordpress, but is hosted by another entity. Right now I'm doing the obvious thing (making sure WP and all plugins are current) but am trying to figure out what else I can do at my level before I check with the host, and to determine what might have happened.  My organization receives a LOT of .pdfs (people email us things to print),  so I thought that might have been a vector, but all of the computers I use at work to do updates have been scanned by both Microsoft Defender and Malwarebytes. I haven't added anything new to the website recently except for the usual pictures and a link to a very simple google form. Removing the link had no effect.

Answer (score 1):

The site seems it has been hacked. It may be via an oudated core/plugin/theme of WordPress or any other service in the same host user account.

To try to solve it, here you have extensive collection of procedures.

https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/faq-my-site-was-hacked/

If you have shell access, WP-CLI may help with easy "core verify-checksums" and "doctor check --all" if available.

Cleaning an attack is usually a hard and long required time task.

Comment: Thank you.  I think I am seeing some progress since I fully updated wordpress, all plugins and themes --   the redirect isn't appearing, though there's a delay before the page loads so I think the redirect is TRYING to appear.

Comment: Pleased tu know it helps, it sounds as there is contamination remaining. Verify the content of wp-config-php, is a typically contamined file. Check it against a non-corrupted one or an old backup for unexpected lines. Loading code via include from wp-content/uploads/ or ofuscated code aren't wellcome there.

Also, check the content to remove any *.php files in wp-content/uploads/ and non WP files in the root folder.